# ConvertToDouble returns an "integer" value

Tags: c#, string, double

Suppose I have a string lile `"168.255157"`, when I use ConvertToDouble(str) the returned value is 168255157 instead of 168.255157;

Why?

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: What is your current culture?

Comment: are you sure it doesnt return `168255157.0`? because this isn't an integer

Comment: @Habib: Indeed thanks a lot, should've put it as an answer though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culture on your machine probably does not consider the decimal seperator to be '.' but ','. Try with this:

```
Convert.ToDouble("168.255157", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Edit: I confirmed that this was happening on my machine when I was using the wrong separator. This:

```
Convert.ToDouble("168,255157", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also returned 168255157.0. You should always bear in mind the culture you are using when parsing strings.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick, Habib answered before you as a comment. Thanks